# Looking for a shuffle radio mp3 player

Tags: looking-for-a-script

I'm looking for a shuffle radio MP3 player that I can embed in my site which:

- shows album and title and
- link to buy track and album in shop

Like this one: http://phpfoxmods.net/clients/productsview.php?id=7

But this is integrated with MP3 community. MP3 broadcast should be secured, free or paid solution? Better integrated with shop or WP?